# Transaction synchronization not active for incoming JMS message

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, spring-transactions, spring-jms

I am using Apache Camel to send messages to my Java service. I have kept `transacted=true` on consumer route. I also need to send e-mail on successfully processing of JMS messages.

I am using below code to register synchronization and send e-mail only after transaction is committed.

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter(){
     @Override
     public void afterCommit(){
         sendMail(mailBody); 
     }
});
```

**Problem:** incoming transaction from Camel is not synchronized and I am getting

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction synchronization is not active

I tried calling `transactionsynchronizationmanager.initsynchronization()` - I am not getting any exception but `afterCommit()` method is never called.

```
transactionsynchronizationmanager.initsynchronization();
TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter(){
     @Override
     public void afterCommit(){
         sendMail(mailBody); //never called
     }
});
```

Same code is working when request is received via spring mvc controller (through Spring Transaction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to turn on transacted on the route to enable spring transaction. The option `transacted=true` on the JMS endpoint is NOT spring-transaction, but its only for JMS acknowledge mode to be set as transacted. They are not the same.

So in your Camel route, setup spring transaction as well, eg

```
from jms
  transacted
```

See more details in the Camel docs: http://camel.apache.org/transactional-client.html or even better if you have a copy of the Camel in Action book (1st or 2nd ed) then it has a fully chapter devoted to transactions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working after setting transacted=true on route. I was actually setting transacted=true in JMSConfigutaion which is incorrect.

Comment: Okay maybe you would mark this question as answered then